# Finding and changing filenames of different media files (photos, videos)

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

My tool should eventually change all media files' names to one qualified format *yyyymmdd_hhmmss [optional desc].xxx*:

- If it's an image, the date is taken from "Date Taken" property of the file.
- If it's a video it should already have that format otherwise it's renamed to literrally YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.MP4
- If it's a video file and has a metadata file, then the "Date Taken" is taken from that metadata file.

I chose a specific design to implement my task. I tried to implement in such way so I could later write unit tests (I know that I should have started with the unit tests first) and use Dependency injection. Each type of media file implements a `ExtractQualifiedName` method which is responsible to extract the DateTaken and then it's used to rename the file. I also created *Loaders* that load specific media files. At first it seemed like this is the right approach since files have common functionality and I used factories to create the file types, but as I added another type `CameraVideoFile` I could not use factory anymore in corresponding `CameraVideoFilesLoader` loader and it seems that the `CameraVideoFile` does not have much common with the rest files, for example this file will always come in non-qualified format and therefore should not inherit from `MediaFile`.

Can someone tell me if my design has correct direction?

I included as much code as I could omitting irrelevant parats

````
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var op = ArgumentParser.Parse(args);
       if(op.Action == "photo-convert")
             ConvertPhotoNames(...)
       else if(op.Action == "video-convert")
             ConvertVideoNames(...)
       else if(op.Action == "modify-video-date")
             ModifyVideoDate(...)
       ...
   }

   private static void ConvertPhotoNames(DirectoryInfo sourceDir)
   {
       var filesLoader = new PhotoFilesLoader();
       // responsible to generate a name in case such file exists (e.g. adding (0))
       var fileNameGenerator = new UniqueFileNameGenerator();
       var fileNameHandler = new MediaFileNameHandler(filesLoader, fileNameGenerator);
       fileNameHandler.ConvertName(sourceDir);
   }
   
   private static void ConvertCameraVideoNames(DirectoryInfo sourceDir)
   {
       var filesLoader = new CameraVideoFilesLoader();
       // responsible to generate a name in case such file exist (e.g. adding (0))
       var fileNameGenerator = new UniqueFileNameGenerator();
       var fileNameHandler = new MediaFileNameHandler(filesLoader, fileNameGenerator);
       fileNameHandler.ConvertName(sourceDir);
   }

   private static void ConvertVideoNames(DirectoryInfo sourceDir)
   {
       var filesLoader = new VideoFilesLoader();
       // responsible to generate a name in case such file exist (e.g. adding (0))
       var fileNameGenerator = new UniqueFileNameGenerator();
       var fileNameHandler = new MediaFileNameHandler(filesLoader, fileNameGenerator);
       fileNameHandler.ConvertName(sourceDir);
   }
}

public class MediaFileNameHandler : IMediaFileNameHandler
{
   public void ConvertName(DirectoryInfo sourceDir)
   {
      foreach (var file in _filesLoader.GetFiles(sourceDir))
      {
         if (!file.Name.IsQualifiedName)
         {
             if (file.ExtractQualifiedName())
             {
                 var newFileInfo = _fileNameGenerator.GenerateName(file);
                 file.Rename(newFileInfo.FullName);
             }
         }
      }
   }
}

public class QualifiedNameInfo
{
   public bool IsQualifiedName { get; private set; }
   public DateTime DateTaken { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MediaFile
{
     public QualifiedNameInfo Name { get; private set; }

     public abstract bool ExtractQualifiedName();
     public MediaFile(string filePath)
     {
        Name = new QualifiedNameInfo(filePath);
     }
}

public class PhotoFile : MediaFile
{
    public override bool ExtractQualifiedName()
    {
       // get DateTaken from file's DateTaken property 
       // Name.DateTaken = ...
    }
}

public class VideoFile : MediaFile
{
    public override bool ExtractQualifiedName()
    {
       // the file should already be in correct format
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CameraVideoFile : MediaFile
{
    public CameraVideoFile(string metaFile, FileInfo videoFile) {...}
    public override bool ExtractQualifiedName()
    {
       // get DateTaken from meta file
       // Name.DateTaken = ...
    }
}

public interface IMediaFilesLoader
{
    IEnumerable<MediaFile> GetFiles(DirectoryInfo dir);
}

public class PhotoFilesLoader : IMediaFilesLoader
{
    public IEnumerable<MediaFile> GetFiles(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        var factory = new MediaFileFactory();
        var files = dir.EnumerateFiles()
                       .Where(f => f.Extension.IsImageExtension())
                       .Select(f => factory.Create(f.FullName));
        return files;
    }
}

public class VideoFilesLoader : IMediaFilesLoader
{
    public IEnumerable<MediaFile> GetFiles(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        var factory = new MediaFileFactory();
        var files = dir.EnumerateFiles()
                       .Where(f => f.Extension.IsVideoExtension())
                       .Select(f => factory.Create(f.FullName));
        return files;
    }
}

public class CameraVideoFilesLoader : IMediaFilesLoader
{
    public IEnumerable<MediaFile> GetFiles(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
       // [C0045M01.XML, C0045.MP4] - first 5 letters of meta filename is the filename of the video
        foreach (var metaFile in dir.EnumerateFiles(".xml"))
        {
            var mp4Filename = metaFile.Name.Substring(0, 5);
            var mp4File = new FileInfo(metaFile.DirectoryName + "\\" + mp4Filename + ".mp4");
            yield return new CameraVideoFile(metaFile, mp4File);
        }                
    }
}
```
````

Comment: @BCdotWEB, after reading the attached link, I think the main problem was in the title like you mentioned. I've updated the title.

Comment: You have tagged your question with `design-patterns`. Why?

Comment: You probably want to allow to convert all support file types at once. This can significantly improve the performance as it eliminates the need to enumerate the same directory multiple times (once for each file type).

Comment: @PeterCsala, one of my issues that I mention in the post is that I cannot use factory with `CameraVideoFilesLoader` like I did with `VideoFilesLoader` for example and thought maybe someone can suggest anything. Maybe even refactor the code. Or maybe the way I did is the correct one and it's ok to not able to use factory in that function.

Comment: @BionicCode, each method is called depending on the arguments that were passed to `Main`. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Program`

#### `ConvertXYZ`

- If you look at the definitions of these three methods then you can easily spot that the only difference is the `IMediaFilesLoader` instance

  - So, you can have a single `Convert` method which can anticipate two parameters

```
private static void Convert(DirectoryInfo sourceDir, IMediaFilesLoader filesLoader)
    => new MediaFileNameHandler(filesLoader, new UniqueFileNameGenerator()).ConvertName(sourceDir);
```

- You did not share with us the source code of the `UniqueFileNameGenerator` so I can't be sure but my gut feeling says that you can have a single instance and reuse it multiple times

```
private static readonly UniqueFileNameGenerator fileNameGenerator = new();
private static void Convert(DirectoryInfo sourceDir, IMediaFilesLoader filesLoader)
    => new MediaFileNameHandler(filesLoader, fileNameGenerator).ConvertName(sourceDir);
```

#### `Main`

- With above `Convert` method you can rewrite your `if` - `else if` - `else if` statement

```
IMediaFilesLoader filesLoader = op.Action switch
{
    "photo-convert" => new PhotoFilesLoader(),
    "video-convert" => new CameraVideoFilesLoader(),
    "modify-video-date" => new VideoFilesLoader(),
    _ => null
};

if(filesLoader == default)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Specified action is unknown");
    Environment.Exit(-1);
    return;
}

Convert(dirInfo, filesLoader);
```

- Depending on the command line parameter you instantiate the appropriate `IMediaFilesLoader` implementation

  - If the specified argument is not matching with any of the predefined values then you can exit early and gracefully
  - If everything is fine then you can call the `Convert` with the two parameters

### `MediaFileNameHandler`

#### `ConvertName`

- The two if statements can be combined into a single
- You can take advantage of LINQ and transform that single if statement into a `Where` filter

```
var toBeRenamedFiles = _filesLoader.GetFiles(sourceDir)
    .Where(file => !file.Name.IsQualifiedName && file.ExtractQualifiedName());

foreach (var file in toBeRenamedFiles)
    file.Rename(_fileNameGenerator.GenerateName(file).FullName);
```

- With this modification we could get rid of two levels of indentation
- Now the core logic is not surrounded with guard expressions

### `QualifiedNameInfo` and `MediaFile`

- Your code will not compile since the `QualifiedNameInfo` class does not have a constructor which anticipates a parameter
- Anyway, I still don't understand how would you want to map a `string` to a `bool` and a `DateTime`

### `PhotoFilesLoader`

#### `GetFiles`

- I suppose that `MediaFileFactory` is stateless so it can be created once and used many times

  - If that's true than you can use expression bodied method feature here

```
public IEnumerable<MediaFile> GetFiles(DirectoryInfo dir)
    => dir.EnumerateFiles()
            .Where(file => file.Extension.IsImageExtension())
            .Select(file => factory.Create(file.FullName));
```

- Basically the same can be applied for `VideoFilesLoader` as well since the only difference is the `IsXYZExtension` call

### `CameraVideoFilesLoader`

#### `GetFiles`

- Other implementations of the `IMediaFilesLoader` seemed really generic

  - But this looks really specialized
- I'm not a huge fan of magic strings, but if you really need that then please prefer to create a dedicated constant for that with a meaningful name

```
const int CommonPartLength = 5;
```

- Instead of using string concatenation for file path please prefer `Path.Combine` method

```
var mp4FileName = metaFile.Name.Substring(0, CommonPartLength);
var mp4FilePath = Path.Combine(metaFile.DirectoryName + $"{mp4FileName}.mp4");
var mp4FileInfo = new FileInfo(mp4FilePath);
```

Comment: I hope you realize that I did not provide ALL code but just the relevant parts. Missing 'ctor does not mean it does not exist! Also, I simplified many things. Your remarks are merely style comments which are very individual. My question was regarding `CameraVideoFile` and `CameraVideoFilesLoader`.

Comment: @theateist Since you are the only one who knows what `MediaFileFactory` does, then how do you expect to provide any valuable feedback on its usage?

Comment: I thought it's self-explanatory since `GetFiles` returns `IEnumerable<MediaFile>` meaning `MediaFileFactory` creates an instance of `PhotoFile` or `VideoFile` or `CameraVideoFile` or other types that might be added in the future. I did not think that the actual implementation of `factory.Create` is needed for my questions.

Comment: @theateist Then I really don't understand what kind of suggestion are you looking for? If your question is that can the `CameraVideoFilesLoader`'s `GetFiles` be rewritten in a way to use your `factory` then the answer is yes. Either you have to introduce a `Create` overload which accepts two parameters Or extend the current one with an optional second argument. Inside the `Create` you can easily branch.

Comment: yes, overloading factory that's what actually I thought to do. But, since I'm still not convinced that `CameraVideoFile` should inherit from `MediaFile` since `CameraVideoFile` is different from `PhotoFile` and `VideoFile` I didn't include this change.

Comment: @theateist Since both the metafile and the video file are needed for `CameraVideoFile`, that's why inheriting from `MediaFile` is not the best solution. Maybe inheriting from a `Tuple<MediaFile, MediaFile>` or a different class would make more sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133991/discussion-between-theateist-and-peter-csala).

Comment: @theateist Do you have any further question? If not then can you please choose an answer from the posts?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(op.Action == "photo-convert")
     ConvertPhotoNames(...)
else if(op.Action == "video-convert")
     ConvertVideoNames(...)
else if(op.Action == "modify-video-date")
     ModifyVideoDate(...)
```

This is an OCP violation. Essentially, the way you've approached the problem requires you to continually maintain the list of options. It leaves the door open to forgetting to update things and, when mistakes occur, the potential to break things that worked before the update. That's not good.

It's more OCP-friendly to rewrite your code in a way that you don't have to touch it anymore, or as infrequently as possible. Not touching the code leads to not accidentally breaking the code. You'd be looking at something along the lines of:

```
foreach(var converter in converters) 
{
    if(converter.CanConvert(action))
        converter.Convert(...);
}
```

*This is just one straightforward example of many possible solutions.*

Based on your code, you seem to understand polymorphism and the adapter pattern; so I'll leave the implementation to you.
The main takeaway here is that my above snippet would never need to be touched when more converters were added to the system - which is precisely what OCP urges you to do.

---

> so I could later write unit tests (I know that I should have started with the unit tests first)

TDD and red/green refactoring is definitely a valid avenue, but it is not the only valid avenue. You could have written your tests first, but you did not *need* to.

> I tried to implement in such way so I could later write unit tests (I know that I should have started with the unit tests first) and use Dependency injection

If you want to be unit test and DI-friendly, you should avoid statics as much as you can (barring pure functions etc, which is not on topic for your snippet). Those high level `ConvertBlaBla()` functions should have been avoided and not made static.

Ideally, you'd want to move to an instanced environment as soon as possible. For inspiration, have a look at e.g. a new WebAPI .NET Core project. It has a static `Main` entry point, but it pretty much only starts up the instanced process in which the application's logic lives.

---

> My tool should eventually change all media files' names to one qualified format yyyymmdd_hhmmss [optional desc].xxx

What surprises me about your approach is that you're not handling a directory in its entirety, but you are specifically converting one type of file at a time. I'm not sure if this is done intentionally or because you did not yet consider/figure out a way to have the logic deal with all types of files at the same time.

If you look back at my earlier suggestion, it can very easily be adapted to account for this:

```
foreach(var converter in converters) 
{
    if(converter.CanConvert(file))   <--- Check the file in question, not the action
        converter.Convert(...);
}
```

Of course, I'm glossing over how you find the files in the first place, but you already know how to do this since you're doing it inside your `IMediaFilesLoader` implementations.

Overall, I would shift the order of operations here. I'm omitting small implementation details because your code already proves you know how to handle them, but I would redesign the algorithm to be more along the lines of:

```
var files = GetFiles("*.*");
var converters = GetConverters();

foreach(var file in files)
foreach(var converter in converters)
{
    if(converter.CanConvert(file))
    {
        converter.Convert(file);            
        break; // This breaks the foreach-converter and moves to the next file.
    }
}
```

This is just a high-level overview, but it makes it easier to parse any arbitrary set of files, instead of having to repeat the process for each type of file you wish to be able to convert.

Some remarks:

- How you aggregate all your converters is up to you. It could be a config file, or you could use reflection to load all implementations of your converter interface, or you could have a dedicated factory. This is a trade-off based on what you want/need.
- How you collect the files is similarly up to you. It could be a fixed location (relative to the application), it could be in a config file, it could be a runtime parameter. It could recursively look for files in all subdirectories. It could possibly only filter on specific extensions (or exclude specific ones). This is up to you to fill in as you need.

Comment: I lack the time for a more in-depth review. I will amend it if I get the chance. I hope the review as is already helps you.

Comment: yes, I intentionally do not handle all types of files at once. The `Main` method is just a high-level of what it does, not how it does it exactly. In any case, the main concern, as I mentioned in the post, was more ragarding `CameraVideoFile`, whether it should inherit from `MediFile` since `CameraVideoFile` is different than `PhotoFile' or 'VideoFile'. Also regarding `CameraVideoFilesLoader` that cannot use factory as other loaders (`PhotoLader`, `VideoLoader`) do.